# How to change date format(d.m.Y) to year(Y) & find annual cumulative sum?

Tags: r, date, format, dplyr, cumsum

I have a  2 columns dataframe x as shown below. The "Publication.Date" column carry the format of "%d.%m.%Y". Is there anyway to create a new column of "year" with the format of "%Y" from the "Publication.Date"?

```
head(x,10)
   Publication.Date n
1        1979-09-05 1
2        1979-09-19 1
3        1980-03-19 1
4        1980-10-01 1
5        1980-12-10 1
6        1981-01-07 1
7        1981-04-02 1
8        1981-05-06 1
9        1981-11-18 1
10       1982-01-20 2
```

I tried create a new column of cumulative sum using dplyr (as shown as below) but actually I wanted to create a new column of "Annual cumulative sum, N" that is  by adding up "n" anually.

```
y <- mutate(x, N=cumsum(n))

head(y,10)
   Publication.Date n  N
1        1979-09-05 1  1
2        1979-09-19 1  2
3        1980-03-19 1  3
4        1980-10-01 1  4
5        1980-12-10 1  5
6        1981-01-07 1  6
7        1981-04-02 1  7
8        1981-05-06 1  8
9        1981-11-18 1  9
10       1982-01-20 2 11
```

My desired outcome should be as below. Appreciating any of your kind advice. Thanks.

```
         Year  n  N
1        1979  2  2
3        1980  3  5
6        1981  4  9
10       1982  2 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either extract the 'Year' using regex, group by that and use `summarise` to get the desired output.  Starting from 'y' from the OP's post

```
y %>% 
   group_by(Year= sub('-.*', '', Publication.Date)) %>%
   summarise(n= sum(n), N= last(N))
#    Year     n     N
#   (chr) (int) (int)
#1  1979     2     2
#2  1980     3     5
#3  1981     4     9
#4  1982     2    11
```

Or use `year` from `library(lubridate)` to extract 'Year' and use `summarise`.

```
library(lubridate)
y %>% 
   group_by(Year = year(as.Date(Publication.Date))) %>% 
   summarise(n= sum(n), N= last(N))
#    Year     n     N
#   (int) (int) (int)
#1  1979     2     2
#2  1980     3     5
#3  1981     4     9
#4  1982     2    11
```

---

If we are using `data.table`, we convert the initial dataset to 'data.table' (`setDT(x)`, grouped by the 'Year' (extracted using `year`), get the `sum` of 'n', create a new column 'N' by doing the `cumsum` of 'n'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, list(n= sum(n)), .(Year= year(Publication.Date))][, N:= cumsum(n)][]
#   Year n  N
#1: 1979 2  2
#2: 1980 3  5
#3: 1981 4  9
#4: 1982 2 11
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg I loaded `data.table`.  So, it should be from there or just to create some novelty, it can be from `lubridate`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this manually, but I would get the `year` function from `data.table` and just do something like directly on your original data set `x`

```
library(data.table)
x %>%
  group_by(Year = year(Publication.Date)) %>%
  tally() %>%
  mutate(N = cumsum(n))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# 
#    Year     n     N
#   (int) (int) (int)
# 1  1979     2     2
# 2  1980     3     5
# 3  1981     4     9
# 4  1982     2    11
```

---

Though I would just do without calculating `n` a priori

```
x %>%
  count(Year = year(Publication.Date)) %>%
  mutate(N = cumsum(n))
# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# 
#    Year     n     N
#   (int) (int) (int)
# 1  1979     2     2
# 2  1980     3     5
# 3  1981     4     9
# 4  1982     1    10
```

But this doesn't *exactly* match your desired output because you predefined `n` without actually providing the full data, but this approach seems better to me anyway.

Comment: Thanks alot @david-arenburg ~ This is very helpful but mind me asking what exactly does %>% means ? Really appreciate your help since I'm still new to R.

Comment: Read [this](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/07/magrittr-simplifying-r-code-with-pipes.html)